# My Xamarin Code for on screen Drawing is not able to be Drawn on even though I followed tutorial code

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

Hi guys I used the code in in this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/paths/finger-paint) and modification with this forum post (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/178190/how-to-fix-cannot-convert-from-touchtracking-touchtrackingpoint-to-xamarin-forms-point) for making on screen drawing. Below is my C# code for Xamarin:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SkiaSharp;
using SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;
using TouchTracking;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MathKumu.Pages
{
    public partial class WorkPage : ContentPage
    {
        Dictionary<long, SKPath> inProgressPaths = new Dictionary<long, SKPath>();
        List<SKPath> completedPaths = new List<SKPath>();

        SKPaint paint = new SKPaint
        {
            Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
            Color = SKColors.Black,
            StrokeWidth = 10,
            StrokeCap = SKStrokeCap.Round,
            StrokeJoin = SKStrokeJoin.Round
        };

        public WorkPage(TopicsData topic)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Title = topic.MathType;
        }

        void OnTouchEffectAction(object sender, TouchActionEventArgs args)
        {
            switch (args.Type)
            {
                case TouchActionType.Pressed:
                    if (!inProgressPaths.ContainsKey(args.Id))
                    {
                        SKPath path = new SKPath();
                        //path.MoveTo(ConvertToPixel(args.Location));
                        path.MoveTo(ConvertToPixel(new Point(args.Location.X, args.Location.Y)));
                        inProgressPaths.Add(args.Id, path);
                        canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                    }
                    break;

                case TouchActionType.Moved:
                    if (inProgressPaths.ContainsKey(args.Id))
                    {
                        SKPath path = inProgressPaths[args.Id];
                        //path.LineTo(ConvertToPixel(args.Location));
                        path.MoveTo(ConvertToPixel(new Point(args.Location.X, args.Location.Y)));
                        canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                    }
                    break;

                case TouchActionType.Released:
                    if (inProgressPaths.ContainsKey(args.Id))
                    {
                        completedPaths.Add(inProgressPaths[args.Id]);
                        inProgressPaths.Remove(args.Id);
                        canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                    }
                    break;

                case TouchActionType.Cancelled:
                    if (inProgressPaths.ContainsKey(args.Id))
                    {
                        inProgressPaths.Remove(args.Id);
                        canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        //SKPoint ConvertToPixel(TouchTrackingPoint location)
        //{
        //    return new SKPoint((float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width * location.X / canvasView.Width),
        //                       (float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Height * location.Y / canvasView.Height));
        //}

        SKPoint ConvertToPixel(Point pt)
        {
            return new SKPoint((float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width * pt.X / canvasView.Width),
                               (float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Height * pt.Y / canvasView.Height));
        }

        void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
        {
            SKCanvas canvas = args.Surface.Canvas;
            canvas.Clear();

            foreach (SKPath path in completedPaths)
            {
                canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
            }

            foreach (SKPath path in inProgressPaths.Values)
            {
                canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
             xmlns:tt="clr-namespace:TouchTracking.Forms;assembly=TouchTracking.Forms"
             x:Class="MathKumu.Pages.WorkPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
            <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView"
                               PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" />
            <Grid.Effects>
                <tt:TouchEffect Capture="True"
                                TouchAction="OnTouchEffectAction" />
            </Grid.Effects>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

On the iPhone simulator it displays the canvas however it is unable to be drawn on. Can you guys please assist me with this? Thank you.

Comment: did you implement the platform specific code for TouchEffect?

Comment: @Jason I used the NuGet package TouchTracking. What do you mean by "platform specific code for TouchEffect"? Thank you.

Comment: TouchEffect.cs and TouchRecognizer.cs, as seen here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Effects/TouchTrackingEffect/TouchTrackingEffect/TouchTrackingEffect.iOS.  I'm not familiar with the nuget package, it may do the same thing.

Comment: @Jason I tried to use the way the way the demo made their namespace touch tracking with all the c sharp classes beginning with touch also with putting toucheffect.cs and touchrecognizer.cs . I also removed the nuget package touchtracking as that had conflicts with the touchtracking namespace they made in their demo. My code now has the error: XLS0419: Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'TouchTracking' that could not be found. Can you please assist me with this? Thank you.

Comment: you need to fix this `xmlns:tt="clr-namespace:TouchTracking.Forms;assembly=TouchTracking.Forms"`

Comment: @Jason the fix you mentioned requires the nuget package TouchTracking.Forms

Comment: no, that is still pointing to the package you removed.  You need to fix it to point to the actual namespace the touch classes are in. I'd suggest you take the time to review the sample app in the tutorial you're following to understand what they are actually doing.

Comment: @Jason In order to make it point to the actual namespace the touch classes are in I did a clean on my project and now it works. Thank you very much for your help and I will definitely review how the touch classes work more deeply.

Comment: You can write your solution in the answer and mark it which will help more people with same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a conversation with @Jason I had to put TouchEffect.cs and TouchRecognizer.cs into my project's .IOS folder. And then in my project's folder where all my xaml files are I had to put TouchActionEventArgs.cs, TouchActionEventHandler.cs, TouchActionType.cs, and TouchEffect.cs. This is all from https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Effects/TouchTrackingEffect/TouchTrackingEffect. And after all that I had to clean the project because I had the NuGet package TouchTracking before. Thank you @Jason for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to use the the built-in touch events.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.views.forms.skcanvasview.touch?view=skiasharp-views-forms-1.68.1

I have a sample here which does just that:
https://github.com/mattleibow/SkiaSharpDemo/blob/master/SkiaSharpDemo/SkiaSharpDemo/MainPage.xaml.cs#L113

Comment: thanks I will take a look at that later but for now my code works